# Windows Docker build failure - ./mvnw - bad interpreter - exit code: 126

Tags: windows, docker

when I try to build a docker image with Windows 10 in powershell or git bash shell I am getting the following error:

```
#0 0.385 /bin/sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw install -DskipTests]: exit code: 126
```

Does anybody know the solution to this?

Comment: Could be wrong line-endings in your script

Comment: Try running a command like `dos2unix` to change the line endings (removing the U+000D carriage-return bytes, which print as `^M`).